# System properties for Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, wildfly

In Wildfly, there are a set of system properties set that you can call System.getProperties() on to get what the Wildfly root directory is, config directory, deployment directory, data directory, etc. [See here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/General+configuration+concepts) under the "Paths" heading.

Is there a similar page that shows what they are for Tomcat? I've been looking around but can't seem to find one.

Answer (score -1):

You can add your own JSP in your tomcat environment with this code inside :

## System Properties:

```
<table>
    <%
        Enumeration e = System.getProperties().keys();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = (String) e.nextElement();
    %><tr>
        <td><%=name%><td><%=System.getProperty(name)%> <%
     }
 %>

</table>
```